# I keep getting an error that a specific class has not been imported and the functions are not define in this flutter code

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

So I have this kind of a big project and i keep getting this issue with the code where when i try to create an object of the animation class, it wont detect the class in itself and keeps throwing an error saying the function of that specific class does not exist and to try importing that class.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:extended_image/extended_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http_client_helper/http_client_helper.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart';
import 'package:image_editor/image_editor.dart';
import 'package:wechat_assets_picker/wechat_assets_picker.dart';

Future<Uint8List?> cropImageDataWithDartLibrary(
    {required ExtendedImageEditorState state}) async {
  debugPrint('dart library start cropping');

  ///crop rect base on raw image
  final Rect? cropRect = state.getCropRect();

  //debugPrint('getCropRect : $cropRect');

  // in web, we can't get rawImageData due to .
  // using following code to get imageCodec without download it.
  // final Uri resolved = Uri.base.resolve(key.url);
  // // This API only exists in the web engine implementation and is not
  // // contained in the analyzer summary for Flutter.
  // return ui.webOnlyInstantiateImageCodecFromUrl(
  //     resolved); //

  final Uint8List data = kIsWeb &&
          state.widget.extendedImageState.imageWidget.image
              is ExtendedNetworkImageProvider
      ? await _loadNetwork(state.widget.extendedImageState.imageWidget.image
          as ExtendedNetworkImageProvider)

      ///toByteData is not work on web
      ///https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44908
      // (await state.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))
      //     .buffer
      //     .asUint8List()
      : state.rawImageData;

  final EditActionDetails editAction = state.editAction!;

  final DateTime time1 = DateTime.now();

  //Decode source to Animation. It can holds multi frame.
  Animation? src;
  //LoadBalancer lb;
  if (kIsWeb) {
    src = decodeAnimation(data);
  } else {
    src = await compute(decodeAnimation, data);
  }
  if (src != null) {
    //handle every frame.
    src.frames = src.frames.map((Image image) {
      final DateTime time2 = DateTime.now();
      //clear orientation
      image = bakeOrientation(image);

      if (editAction.needCrop) {
        image = copyCrop(image, cropRect!.left.toInt(), cropRect.top.toInt(),
            cropRect.width.toInt(), cropRect.height.toInt());
      }

      if (editAction.needFlip) {
        late Flip mode;
        if (editAction.flipY && editAction.flipX) {
          mode = Flip.both;
        } else if (editAction.flipY) {
          mode = Flip.horizontal;
        } else if (editAction.flipX) {
          mode = Flip.vertical;
        }
        image = flip(image, mode);
      }

      if (editAction.hasRotateAngle) {
        image = copyRotate(image, editAction.rotateAngle);
      }
      final DateTime time3 = DateTime.now();
      debugPrint('${time3.difference(time2).toString()} : crop/flip/rotate');
      return image;
    }).toList();
  }

  /// you can encode your image
  ///
  /// it costs much time and blocks ui.
  //var fileData = encodeJpg(src);

  /// it will not block ui with using isolate.
  //var fileData = await compute(encodeJpg, src);
  //var fileData = await isolateEncodeImage(src);
  List<int>? fileData;
  debugPrint('start encode');
  final DateTime time4 = DateTime.now();
  if (src != null) {
    final bool onlyOneFrame = src.numFrames == 1;
    //If there's only one frame, encode it to jpg.
    if (kIsWeb) {
      fileData = onlyOneFrame ? encodeJpg(src.first) : encodeGifAnimation(src);
    } else {
      //fileData = await lb.run<List<int>, Image>(encodeJpg, src);
      fileData = onlyOneFrame
          ? await compute(encodeJpg, src.first)
          : await compute(encodeGifAnimation, src);
    }
  }
  final DateTime time5 = DateTime.now();
  debugPrint('${time5.difference(time4).toString()} : encode');
  debugPrint('${time5.difference(time1).toString()} : total time');
  return Uint8List.fromList(fileData!);
}

Future<Uint8List?> cropImageDataWithNativeLibrary(
    {required ExtendedImageEditorState state}) async {
  debugPrint('native library start cropping');

  final Rect? cropRect = state.getCropRect();
  final EditActionDetails action = state.editAction!;

  final int rotateAngle = action.rotateAngle.toInt();
  final bool flipHorizontal = action.flipY;
  final bool flipVertical = action.flipX;
  final Uint8List img = state.rawImageData;

  final ImageEditorOption option = ImageEditorOption();

  if (action.needCrop) {
    option.addOption(ClipOption.fromRect(cropRect!));
  }

  if (action.needFlip) {
    option.addOption(
        FlipOption(horizontal: flipHorizontal, vertical: flipVertical));
  }

  if (action.hasRotateAngle) {
    option.addOption(RotateOption(rotateAngle));
  }

  final DateTime start = DateTime.now();
  final Uint8List? result = await ImageEditor.editImage(
    image: img,
    imageEditorOption: option,
  );

  debugPrint('${DateTime.now().difference(start).toString()} ：total time');
  return result;
}

Future<dynamic> isolateDecodeImage(List<int> data) async {
  final ReceivePort response = ReceivePort();
  await Isolate.spawn(_isolateDecodeImage, response.sendPort);
  final dynamic sendPort = await response.first;
  final ReceivePort answer = ReceivePort();
  // ignore: always_specify_types
  sendPort.send([answer.sendPort, data]);
  return answer.first;
}

Future<dynamic> isolateEncodeImage(Image src) async {
  final ReceivePort response = ReceivePort();
  await Isolate.spawn(_isolateEncodeImage, response.sendPort);
  final dynamic sendPort = await response.first;
  final ReceivePort answer = ReceivePort();
  // ignore: always_specify_types
  sendPort.send([answer.sendPort, src]);
  return answer.first;
}

void _isolateDecodeImage(SendPort port) {
  final ReceivePort rPort = ReceivePort();
  port.send(rPort.sendPort);
  rPort.listen((dynamic message) {
    final SendPort send = message[0] as SendPort;
    final List<int> data = message[1] as List<int>;
    send.send(decodeImage(data));
  });
}

void _isolateEncodeImage(SendPort port) {
  final ReceivePort rPort = ReceivePort();
  port.send(rPort.sendPort);
  rPort.listen((dynamic message) {
    final SendPort send = message[0] as SendPort;
    final Image src = message[1] as Image;
    send.send(encodeJpg(src));
  });
}

/// it may be failed, due to Cross-domain
Future<Uint8List> _loadNetwork(ExtendedNetworkImageProvider key) async {
  try {
    final Response? response = await HttpClientHelper.get(Uri.parse(key.url),
        headers: key.headers,
        timeLimit: key.timeLimit,
        timeRetry: key.timeRetry,
        retries: key.retries,
        cancelToken: key.cancelToken);
    return response!.bodyBytes;
  } on OperationCanceledError catch (_) {
    //debugPrint('User cancel request ${key.url}.');
    return Future<Uint8List>.error(
        StateError('User cancel request ${key.url}.'));
  } catch (e) {
    return Future<Uint8List>.error(StateError('failed load ${key.url}. \n $e'));
  }
}

class ImageSaver {
  const ImageSaver._();

  static Future<String?> save(String title, Uint8List fileData) async {
    //final String title = '${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg';
    final AssetEntity? imageEntity = await PhotoManager.editor.saveImage(
      fileData,
      title: title,
    );
    final File? file = await imageEntity?.file;
    return file?.path;
  }
}
```

this is the error, it keeps giving me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcLTW.png)

I've tried using the quick fix and it keeps telling me to importing of the following libraries.
html, animation, cupertino, material and widgets. and then theres 2 other options to create the animation class.

I have also tried chatgpt for help but it's pretty much useless as it keeps telling me what i already know.

Comment: You might not have the right flutter version or you did not run `flutter pub get` or when running it an error occurs.

Comment: @LodewykRoux
i've done countless times
plus my flutter is the latest one 3.7.7 

and i also tired deleting pubspec.lock and the rerunning pub get

Comment: It seems you are missing some imports, I searched up decodeAnimation and it seems to be from this package: https://pub.dev/packages/pic, as indicated here: https://pub.dev/documentation/pic/latest/pic/decodeAnimation.html. It seems some of the other errors like `Flip` is also from this package. Check if importing this package works?

Comment: @LodewykRoux
no imports are missing as i am not tryna use html package
decodeAnimation and frame are also part of the ui package but it still wont detect it